# python random in lists

Tags: python, list

This is my current code:

```
import random

while True:
    try:
        num   = int(input("Enter the total number of digits you want to generate:"))
        upper = int(input("Enter your highest number:"))
        lower = int(input("Enter your lowest number:"))

        if upper < 1 or lower < 1 or upper <= lower:
            print ("Sorry, invalid. Make sure your upper bound is higher than lower bound, make sure all numbers are integers greater than 0.")
            continue

        if num < 1:
            print ("Sorry, invalid. Try again.")
            continue

        **mylist = [0] * num
        for x in range (lower, upper):**
```

The part directly above here is the part that I am not quite sure how to go forward on. I want to generate random numbers depending on the number the user enters and within the upper and lower bounds that the user enters into a list that displays here. Can someone guide me through this? thank you!

```
except:
    print ("Sorry, invalid. Try again.")

else:
    print ("Thank you.")
    break
```

Comment: num, upper, and lower are either redundant or conflicting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you replace your `**` lines with the following, using `random.randint(lower, upper)`, you'll display the list you want:

```
mylist = []
for _ in range(num):
    mylist.append(random.randint(lower, upper))

print mylist
```

You could also do this with a list comprehension:

```
mylist = [random.randint(lower, upper) for _ in range(num)]
print mylist
```

Comment: thank you @mvchr, is there a way write the first code so that the same number does not repeat in the list more than once

Comment: @user1762229 see Brenden Brown's answer

Answer (score 1):

you probably need:

```
print [random.randint(lower, upper) for n in range(num)]
```

which displays a list of num random integers with minimum lower and maximum upper (inclusive).

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted a random subset of the numbers between lower and upper, inclusive, you could use:

`random.sample(num, xrange(lower, upper + 1))`

http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.sample

But I think you wanted duplicates to be possible, in which case use one of the other answers.

Comment: That will generate `num` numbers, instead of `num` digits of random numbers.  (The question may be badly worded, on this point.)

Comment: This generates a sequence with no repeats from the population.  What if num is greater than upper-lower?

Comment: sampe gives unique numbers, no repeats, you probably need: print [random.randint(lower, upper) for n in range(num)] which displays a list of num random integer numbers with minimum lower and maximum upper (inclusive).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `randint` to generate numbers in the given range.

Return a random integer **x** such that **a <= x <= b.**

```
import random
print random.randint(a, b)
```

So to generate **N** numbers in the range **a** and **b**

```
numbers = [random.randint(a, b) for i in range(N)]
print numbers
```

Comment: look at the [`random`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html) library.  Don't forget to use `random.seed()`.